# Caudex vs Xylopodium difference

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

I live in Brazil and many plants from the brazilian grasslands/prairies exhibit an structure called, by the brazilian literature, "xylopodium" (or "xilopódio" in portuguese) - which are tickened, underground, lignified structures (root or stem) to store water and nutrients. I couldn't really find any work outside Brazil that mentions this kind of strucutre, and as far as I know, the structure known as "caudex" fits the very same definition. That being said, are these two terms synonyms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The New York Botanic Garden gives the [definition of xylopodium](http://sweetgum.nybg.org/science/glossary/glossary-details/?irn=1703) as:

> An underground, woody, storage organ derived from stems or roots and common in cerrado vegetation.

And the [definition of caudex](http://sweetgum.nybg.org/science/glossary/glossary-details/?irn=435) as:

> A short, vertical, usually woody and persistent stem at or just below the surface of the ground.

I think the main difference here is the focus on the xylopodium as a storage organ, as well as the fact that it is fully underground and can be derived from either the stem or root. A caudex doesn't necessarily primarily provide storage, and as a modified stem, is at or above the surface.

---

*There is also a [definition of xylopodium](https://www.mobot.org/mobot/latindict/keyDetail.aspx?keyWord=xylopodium) meaning the type of fruit found in *Anacardium* (cashews).